# The scope of JavaScript datatypes related question

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I need to know the scope of the follwoing question in the stackexchange network, I am not sure about its relevancy to Stack Overflow:

> I am not able to understand how could undefined and null are going
>   to be datatypes in a programming language! Basically, there is no
>   data! so how?

Comment: No, SO won't be appropriate. Maybe ask at SE Software Engineering.

Comment: Another possibility is [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: In any case, I'd try to clarify that on the chat rooms at these sites first.

Comment: How is this a JavaScript question? Many programming languages have `null` signifying lack of data, JavaScript isn't an exception here. The only difference is that it also has `undefined` which...is the same concept. If you understand what `null` is, the knowledge is transferable to `undefined`. If you don't understand `null`, then it's not really related to JavaScript. Overall it seems like a rather poor question unless there is more to add to it.

Comment: @VLAZ Your comment may be regraded as answer, but it is out of the question's scope. The question is meant by where could it be asked?

Comment: @SaidbakR and I hope that *if* you ask it it's going to actually be a good question. Because as stated it seems poor and might be closed.

Comment: @VLAZ It is just a general example about a topic or a blue print.